# Como mostrar 3 dados por vez nesse printf em linguagem C?

Tags: c

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
//Leitura de arquivo
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  FILE *pont_arq;
  char texto_str[20];
  int contador; 
  //abrindo o arquivo_frase em modo "somente leitura"
  pont_arq = fopen("dadosCadastrais/arquivo.txt", "r");

  //enquanto não for fim de arquivo o looping será executado
  //e será impresso o texto

  while(fgets(texto_str, 20, pont_arq) != NULL)

  printf("%s", texto_str);



  //fechando o arquivo
  fclose(pont_arq);

  getch();
  return(0);
}
```

Tenho os seguintes dados no arquivo bloco de notas(.txt):

```
paulo,joão,antonio,lais,alguemx,alguem2
```

Na execução do programa em c é exibido assim:

```
 paulo,joão,antonio,lais,alguemx,alguem2
```

Como mostrar 3 palavras por linha? exemplo:

```
paulo,joão,antonio

lais,alguemx,alguem2
```

Comment: A função `fgets` lê uma linha, ou no seu caso no máximo 20 caracteres. Se as palavras estão sempre separadas pelo caractere `,` então você pode ler toda a linha (aumente seu limite) e contar as vírgulas inserindo uma quebra de linha a cada 3 vírgulas encontradas. Outra opção é utilizar outra função de leitura e parar a cada vírgula. Note que seu programa fez 2 leituras no while.

Comment: Quais seriam as funções?

Comment: A função de leitura `fscanf`, mas em minha opinião é melhor ler toda a linha com `fgets` e tratar a string lida, por exemplo com a função `strtok`.

Comment: Tambem é possível ler caractere por caractere com `getc` e tokenizar já na entrada de dados.

Comment: gente alguem pode fazer ain  to conseguindo nao